# ¿Por qué "ducentésimo" y no "duocentésimo"?

Tags: historia, números

En del Diccionario de la lengua existe **duodécimo** y por similitud sería esperable que existiera **duocentésimo**, pero no es así: la forma correcta es **ducentésimo**.

De hecho, la forma "duocentésimo" se utiliza, como [aquí](https://naciondeportes.com/zidane-cumplira-200-partidos-con-real-madrid/) (... podría mejorar su récord en el *duocentésimo* cotejo en el que estará a cargo de los jugadores madridistas ...), [aquí](https://seguridaduruguay.info/escolares-y-liceales-realizaron-promesa-y-juramento-a-la-bandera-diario-el-telegrafo/) (En plaza Artigas se conmemoró el *duocentésimo* quincuagésimo quinto aniversario del natalicio ...) o [aquí](https://www.analitica.com/actualidad/actualidad-nacional/asamblea-nacional-sesionara-este-martes-en-maracaibo/) (... para celebrar el Duocentésimo Vigésimo Sexto Aniversario ...).

¿Por qué se produjo esa pérdida de la "o"?

Answer (score 3):

Pues yo casi te diría que la *o* nunca se perdió, dado que nunca estuvo ahí.

> *Fecha la carta en el mes de junio, era de mill e dozientos e setenta e dos años, anno ab incarnacione Domini millesimo ducentesimo trigesimo quarto, regnando el rey don Ferrando en Castiella e en Toledo e en Leon e en Galizia [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Venta de propiedades de la abadía de Silos [Cartulario de Silos]", 1234 (España).

Otro ejemplo algo menos antiguo:

> *Desdel numero centesimo fasta el millesimo son nombres compuestos como ducentesimo. tricentesimo. quadringentesimo. quingentesimo. sescentesimo. septingentesimo octingentesimo. nongentesimo.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

En los diccionarios la voz *ducentésimo* aparece recogida desde 1786 en el *Terreros y Pando*, mientras que la voz *duocentésimo* nunca ha sido recogida, y en el CORDE solo veo ejemplos de *ducentésimo* pero no de *duocentésimo*. Tampoco aparece *duocentésimo* en las [gráficas de Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ducentesimo%2Cducent%C3%A9simo%2Cduocentesimo%2Cduocent%C3%A9simo&corpus=21&case_insensitive=on&year_end=2019&year_start=1500&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cducentesimo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cducent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bducent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDucent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cducentesimo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cducent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bducent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDucent%C3%A9simo%3B%2Cc0), que abarcan desde 1500 hasta 2012. Luego es posible que sea al revés, que la *o* en *duocentésimo* sea una añadidura moderna, fruto tal vez de una excesiva corrección por influencia de *duodécimo* y por el desconocimiento general de los ordinales por encima del quincuagésimo dado su escasísimo uso (según afirma la RAE en su *Gramática* en el [párrafo 21.4h](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=bMEBUlvIYakFiOoR)).

Para terminar, aclarar que *ducentésimo* proviene del latín *ducentesĭmus*, y que en el DLE aparece la voz *[ducientos](https://dle.rae.es/ducientas)*, del latín *ducenti*, como forma en desuso de *doscientos*.